# Visualforce page - not pulling values from related object and not showing table style

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, table

I have the following objects:

**Object: A**

- Picklist: I
- Field: 1
- Field: 2
- Field: 3

**Object: B** (This is where I want the visualforce page (table)

Current visualforce page that works in Object B:

```
<apex:page StandardController="B__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:pageBlock title="Numbers">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:outputField value="{! B__c.1__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! B__c.3__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! B__c.2__c }"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Trying to update it so that I can pull the numbers from the related object. Also trying to change it to a table type. The reason why is because I have a picklist in Object A that I would like to use in the table so I know what numbers belong to what item in the picklist.

```
<apex:page StandardController="B__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:pageBlock title="A Fields">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:outputField value="{! A__r.I__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! A__r.1__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! A__r.2__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! A__r.3__c }"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

this obviously does not work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access parent objects fields like this.

```
<apex:page StandardController="B__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:pageBlock title="A Fields">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:outputField value="{! B__c.A__r.I__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! B__c.A__r.1__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! B__c.A__r.2__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! B__c.A__r.3__c }"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Even for standard objects, it works in a similar way.

```
{!contact.account.name}
```

Comment: I tried that before and it doesn't work. I get an error message "Error: Unknown property ...".

Comment: Sorry. I had a typo. it does work.